# How to view preferenceFragment as card (cardView)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cardview, preferencefragment

I have an `ActionBarActivity` which contains `HorizontalScrollView` to show tabs and fragment under each.
Currently the loaded fragment under each tab is `PreferenceFragment`, but I want it to be card (as part of a `cardView` and this card to contain my `PreferenceFragment`.
I know it is possible to put the `PreferenceFragment` in a container inside `Activity` view, but is it possible to put it in a container of `Fragment` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution will be to implement `ListView` inside the card view.

Here is the card layout :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Notice the `ListView` with the contained `@android:id/list` which is what the `preferenceFragment` requires in order to be inflated.

Answer (score 0):

The layout you inflate for your fragment can be wrapped in a cardview.

Fragment

```
  public View onCreateView(...) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_card_row, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fssr_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

     </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: it crashes, if I remove the `addPreferencesFromResource(preferenceFrag);` I see the card fine - error : `Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class`

Comment: Can you post the xml ?

Comment: sure, of which layout ?, although the error pretty simple, the layout contains `list` which is not `ListView`, which is correct, `preferenceFragment` does contain a list.

Answer (score -2):

The best method I found was to use nested fragments with AppCompat's `getChildFragmentManager()`.

My code that works for the Swipe View I made with my cards and I think will work for you:

PrefsFragment.java:

```
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

}
```

PrefsContainerFragment.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PrefsContainerFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fragment prefsFragment = new PrefsFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.child_fragment, prefsFragment).commit();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pref, container,false);
}


}
```

fragment_pref XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_padding"
tools:context=".PrefFragment"
android:clickable="false">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/child_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

There might be an issue with the `FragmentTransaction` in the `onCreate` method, but as far as I can tell, it works because you use `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);` in the `onCreate` of the child Fragment too. However, if it doesn't work for you, try putting it in `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated`.